# Can I Fill a List using a DataAdapter C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

Suppose I have this code (pseudocode)

```
class SomeClass
{
   class Person
   {
      public static string Name { get; set; }
      public static int Age { get; set; }
   }

   List<Person> person = new List<person>;

   public void SelectPerson()
   {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();

      SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
      conn.Open();

      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name, age FROM person", conn);
      da.Fill(dt);
   }
}
```

Can I fill the List (person) based on the result of my DataAdapter?
How should I do it? Or is there any workaround? Thanks...

Comment: Pwninstein made an interesting point. Why are the name and age on person static?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably the best way is not to read into a datatable first:

```
var dr = new DataReader(....) // Fill in what is needed, can't remember offhand
while(dr.Next())
{
    persons.Add(
        new Person() {
            Name = (string) r["Name"], 
            Age = (int) r["Age"] 
        }
    );
}
```

**Caveat**: You want to close the DataReader/connection quickly, don't do lots of processing. The above code is more efficient than using a DataTable as an intermediary.

But if you do want to use a data table first, you could use LINQ:

```
var list = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new Person() { 
    Name = (string) r["Name"], 
    Age = (int) r["Age"] }
).ToList()
```

or just itterate of dt.Rows and create a new person and add it to the list

You should also use [Using() statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641660/will-a-using-statement-rollback-a-database-transaction-if-an-error-occurs) around your [connection and reader](http://www.w3enterprises.com/articles/using.aspx).

Comment: though the linq version is not working... there is no `dt.Rows.Select` for the data table

Comment: Sorry, use dt.AsEnumerable(), I was not specifically familiar with the dr.Row collection. Post is fixed

Comment: That works --> except for really handling nulls or you get  Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String`     but I realize that wasn't for you to handle errors for the answer :)

Comment: DataReader is not good solution for performance. Maybe some inheritance from DataTable/DataRow would be better

Comment: @Hamid Can you clarify the concerns, what would be a more performant solution? IIRC most solutions to reading data using ADO.NET will use a data reader (including filling a datatable). The only thing I can think of is that  you don't want to keep the datareader open too long, which is achieved by having a tight loop. In most cases DB read performance isn't a big problem.

Comment: @RobertWagner DataReader will takes long time when you want to using it in network system (i.e. Server and client connected via LAN ) and better solution is filling datatable by adapter or command and then creating child objects from datatable rows.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Linq to DataSet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2007/01/26/querying-datasets-introduction-to-linq-to-dataset.aspx) that you could use to do something along these lines

```
var list = (from tr in dt.AsEnumerable()
    select new Person() { 
        Name = tr.Field<string>("Name"), 
        Age = tr.Field<int>("Age") 
    }).ToList();
```

Robert beat me to the answer, just using slightly different syntax.

Comment: This is probably better, I'm not familiar with Linq to DataSets as I avoid them like the plague.

Comment: @Robert Wagner: As do I, but every now and then we have to work with legacy code.

Comment: So true, but thankfully I havn't had the intersection of C# 3.0 and datasets

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other options presented, you could defer the execution until needed with a yield:

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    using( var conn = GetConnection() )
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT name, age FROM person";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand( sql, conn );

        using( SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
        {
            if( rdr == null )
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException( "No People Available." );
            }
            while( rdr.Read() )
            {
                var person = new Person();
                person.Name = rdr["name"].ToString();
                person.Age = Convert.ToInt32 ( rdr["age"] );

                yield return person;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is potentially dangerous as the connection is left open while the the calling code does the iteration. Also, what happens if the caller does not get to the end of the collection? Do the connection get disposed?

Comment: I suppose most code could be potentially dangerous. Your point is understood and should be taken into consideration. Here's a good read on [C# IEnumerator/yield structure with databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803878/c-ienumerator-yield-structure-potentially-bad)

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll want to make your Name and Age fields non-static (so each instance of the class will have their own values for these properties.

Then you could do something like this:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows){
    Person p = new Person(){
        Name = Convert.ToString(row["name"]),
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(row["age"])
    }
    person.Add(p);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Iterate through the items in `dt.Rows` and convert them manually to `Person` objects.

Answer (score -2):

A user recently asked me a question on converting a DataTable to a List<> in .NET 2.0. Here’s the code to do so:

C#

```
// Assuming there is a DataTable called dt

List<DataRow> drlist = new List<DataRow>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    drlist.Add((DataRow)row);
}
```